# Changing div content when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have the following div:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
    <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Daily CVaR</span>
    <div><span class="count">{{ cvar|round(2) }}</span><font size="5">%</font></div>
    <span class="count_bottom">&euro;{{ cvar_pnl|round(2) }} of limit <span style="color:#E74C3C">&euro;x</span></span>
</div>
```

I'd like to be able to click this section to change it to:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
    <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Weekly CVaR</span>
    <div><span class="count">{{ cvar_weekly|round(2) }}</span><font size="5">%</font></div>
    <span class="count_bottom">&euro;{{ cvar_pnl_weekly|round(2) }} of limit <span style="color:#E74C3C">&euro;x</span></span>
</div
```

and then click again to show the same for cvar_monthly. This variable is just a number. Any pointers on how I can go about doing this?

```
        $('.count').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).text()
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function (now) {
                    $(this).text(Math.round(now * 100) / 100);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Show the JS code too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create all elements and just change the visibility instead of changing the content?! This is by far better to maintain and result in much easier code.

```js
$('.tile_stats_count').on('click', function() {
  var clicked = $(this),
      daily = $('.tile_stats_count.daily').hide(0),
      weekly = $('.tile_stats_count.weekly').hide(0),
      monthly = $('.tile_stats_count.monthly').hide(0);

  clicked.is('.daily') ? weekly.show(0) : clicked.is('.weekly') ? monthly.show(0) : daily.show(0);
});
```

```css
.tile_stats_count {
  display: none;
}

.tile_stats_count.default {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count daily default">
    <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Daily CVaR</span>
    <div><span class="count">{{ cvar|round(2) }}</span><font size="5">%</font></div>
    <span class="count_bottom">&euro;{{ cvar_pnl|round(2) }} of limit <span style="color:#E74C3C">&euro;x</span></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count weekly">
    <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Weekly CVaR</span>
    <div><span class="count">{{ cvar_weekly|round(2) }}</span><font size="5">%</font></div>
    <span class="count_bottom">&euro;{{ cvar_pnl_weekly|round(2) }} of limit <span style="color:#E74C3C">&euro;x</span></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count monthly">
    <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Monthly CVaR</span>
    <div><span class="count">{{ cvar_monthly|round(2) }}</span><font size="5">%</font></div>
    <span class="count_bottom">&euro;{{ cvar_pnl_monthly|round(2) }} of limit <span style="color:#E74C3C">&euro;x</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do this with a JS script. First, add an `onClick` event and an ID to your div. Then, write the js script that will change the value of the div:

```js
function changeValue() {
  var toChange = document.getElementById("thisChanges");
  var htmla = "First HTML value";
  var htmlb = "Second HTML Value";

  if (toChange.innerHTML == htmla){
    toChange.innerHTML = htmlb;
  } else {
    toChange.innerHTML = htmla;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count" onclick="changeValue()" ID="thisChanges">
First HTML value
</div>
```

Make sure to include this function in the  tags on your webpage.
If you have any further questions, don't hesitate.

Comment: Please don't use `jsfiddle` for your answers, use SO's own snippet tool for creating examples.

Comment: Wow thats the first time i hear about that

Comment: No problem. It's just better. Within some years jsfiddle may remove snippets and your answer may become invalid of missing some info. Therefore SO snippets are a better choice and it does the same. ;) I've edited your answer for this.

Comment: Beside this, your answer has a little bug too: it only changes on second click. ;) This is because you not thought about the whitespace in your initial `div`.